# Linux Python server wont terminate properly

Tags: python, linux

I made a echo server run on port 5555 and it receives and returns data perfectly but it will not close correctly. When i enter the exit command, it just keeps printing blank output. Can someone please help, thanks.

[Echo working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi3Rm.png)

[Keeps printing received data (which is empty)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2LXs.png)

Server_side code

```
import socket as sk
server_socket = sk.socket(sk.AF_INET, sk.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(sk.SOL_SOCKET, sk.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(("localhost", 5555))
server_socket.listen(1)
connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
while True:
   data_in = connection.recv(1024)
   message = data_in.decode()
   message.strip()
   if message == "quit" or message == "QUIT":
       break
   print("" , message)
   data_out = message.encode()
   connection.send(data_out)
connection.shutdown(sk.SHUT_RDWR)
connection.close()
server_socket.shutdown(sk.SHUT_RDWR)
server_socket.close()
```

Client_side code

```
import socket as sk
client_socket = sk.socket(sk.AF_INET, sk.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('localhost', 5555))
while True:
  #input message
  message = input("Enter message to send or type quit to quit: ")

  #check if user wants to quit
  if message == "quit" or message == "QUIT":
      break

  #encode the user input and send it to the server
  client_socket.send(message.encode())

  #save the data sent by the server
  recmess = client_socket.recv(1024)

  #print the server reply
  print("Server: ", recmess.decode())
  print()

#print student details
print("Connection Closed")

client_socket.shutdown(sk.SHUT_RDWR)
client_socket.close()
```

Comment: Please do not post code or text output as images. [Edit] your question to add it as text and use the code button to format it properly.

Comment: Sorry about that, first time asking a question.                                       Fixed the code, all you need to know about the output is that when i enter quit it just constantly keeps looping with no message and just blank output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are breaking out of the while loop on the client side (in the case of the quit input) prior to sending the message, the server never receives the command to shut down. This means the client will close down while leaving the server up.

One option to fix this issue is to switch the order in which the message is sent to the server (send, then check to close client side)

```
client_socket.send(message.encode())

if message.lower() == 'quit':
    break
```

Hopefully this helps